# Are these 2 quasi poisson glm identical?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

Approach 1:

```
lm.fit <- glm(response ~ 1, offset=log(lam), family="quasipoisson")
summary(lm.fit)
```

Approach 2: Feed summary.glm with a pearson dispersion.

```
lm.fit <- glm(response ~ 1, offset=log(lam), family="poisson")
summary(lm.fit, 
       dispersion=sum(residuals(lm.fit, type="pearson")^2)/df.residual(lm.fit))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, they are not both quasipoisson. The first approach is indeed a quasipoisson but the 2nd `lm.fit` is called a poisson GLM. In approah 1 since you are fitting a quasipoisson, there will be no log-likelihood and therefore there is not any [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) to report in the 1st `summary(lm.fit)` you wrote.
However, in the 2nd approach since you fitted a poisson GLM first, there will be a log-likelihood and even if you plug in the estimated dispersion effect in the summary, you can still see the AIC criteria in the output of your 2nd `summary(lm.fit)`.
So to sum-up, if by identical you mean the same output in the summaries, then the answer is "No", they are not the same.